# how extract html String and add it to UILabel in Xcode using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

1. I have an HMTL String like this:

> ក្នុងសម័យ​អធិរាជ Emperor Meiji ដែល​ឡើងកាន់​អំណាច​ក្នុង​ឆ្នាំ ១៨៦៨ ព្រះអង្គ​បានទទួល​យក​សិទ្ធិ​គ្រប់គ្រង​ប្រទេស​ពេញលេញ ដែល​ផ្ដល់​ដោយ​ស្ដេចត្រាញ់​គ្រប់គ្នា​នៅ​ទូទាំង<!--more-->ប្រទេស ហើយ​ក្នុង​គ្រា​នោះដែរ​ព្រះអង្គ​បាន​ខិតខំ​ពង្រឹង​អាណាចក្រ​ជប៉ុន​ឲ្យ​មាន​ភាពរឹងមាំ ...<div><img width="624" height="353" src="https://www.pmhotnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/B20-24-0416-16-624x353.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="B20-24-0416 (16)" /></div><br />[more] 
>   ➥<i>ប្រភពពីគេហទំព័រ <strong>ប្រជាប្រិយ</strong> - <a href="https://www.pmhotnews.com/2016/04/23/56901.html/" target="_blank">រូបថត​ដ៏​កម្រ​របស់​សាមូរ៉ៃ​ជប៉ុន​ក្នុង​កំលុង​ឆ្នាំ ១៨០០ ដែល​ធ្លាប់តែ​ឮឈ្មោះ​តែ​មិនដែល​បានឃើញ​</a>​​</i>

2. I have a `UILabel` like this:

   ```
   UILabel * contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   ```
3. How can I set text to `contentLabel` with clickable event using Objective-C code?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * strHtmlString = @"Your HTML String";

NSAttributedString * strAttrib = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[strHtmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

contentLabel.attributedText = strAttrib;
```

Hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
contentLabel.text = @"ក្នុងសម័យ​អធិរាជ Emperor Meiji ដែល​ឡើងកាន់​អំណាច​ក្នុង​ឆ្នាំ ១៨៦៨ ព្រះអង្គ​បានទទួល​យក​សិទ្ធិ​គ្រប់គ្រង​ប្រទេស​ពេញលេញ ដែល​ផ្ដល់​ដោយ​ស្ដេចត្រាញ់​គ្រប់គ្នា​នៅ​ទូទាំងប្រទេស ហើយ​ក្នុង​គ្រា​នោះដែរ​ព្រះអង្គ​បាន​ខិតខំ​ពង្រឹង​អាណាចក្រ​ជប៉ុន​ឲ្យ​មាន​ភាពរឹងមាំ ...[more] ➥ប្រភពពីគេហទំព័រ ប្រជាប្រិយ - រូបថត​ដ៏​កម្រ​របស់​សាមូរ៉ៃ​ជប៉ុន​ក្នុង​កំលុង​ឆ្នាំ ១៨០០ ដែល​ធ្លាប់តែ​ឮឈ្មោះ​តែ​មិនដែល​បានឃើញ​​​";
```

You can take tapgesture recognizer on label to handle click